# Override PHP-sdk file in vendor

Tags: magento2, override-model, 3rd-party-library, mod-rewrite, third-party-plugin

I want to override the (PHP sdk)file which is found in the vendor path the path is

> vendor/tamara-solution/php-sdk/src/Tamara/Model/Order/Order.php

**I am attaching my that specific php sdk composer.json file is given below**

---

[image: composer .json]

---

One thing I want to add here is that the file under `php-sdk/src/Tamara/Model/` is not a typical Magento 2 module .these are just core PHP class